# Large keepalive_requests values are severely slowing-down Nginx

Tags: nginx, performance, http, keepalive

When running a bacon (43-byte transparent pixel) load test on Nginx, we have tried several `keepalive_requests` values (from 10 to 100,000) and the optimal value seems to be `10`.

Here are the server HTTP headers of this tiny reply:

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Server: nginx/1.5.6
   Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2013 12:39:45 GMT
   Content-Type: image/gif
   Content-Length: 43
   Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Sep 1970 06:00:00 GMT
   Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx is twice slower with `keepalive_requests 100000` than with `keepalive_requests 10`.

Can you help understanding that result? Or tell what we do wrong?

For reference, here is the [nginx.conf file](http://pastebin.com/Ue4bUM96).

Comment: you'd better ask this on the [nginx-forum/ml](http://forum.nginx.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the comment's suggestion above, I searched the Nginx Forum and the same question titled  [*"Enabling keepalive increases request time"*](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,243267,243267#msg-243267) and posted one month ago was left without any answer.

It looks like a bug. Will have to wait for a fix.

Answer (score -3):

I meet the same problem. I use multi_accept，but my benchmark tool's -c num lower then nginx's 
keepalive_request number，and i user -k argument with benchmark tool the same time. so one of nginx worker will accept and handle the request as many as possible.

You can try to disable multi_accept, then the result may be better.